# Grifar palavras de um parágrafo usando apenas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, for

Como parte de aprendizagem, estou tentando grifar palavras que estão contidas em um parágrafo em um documento `html`. Pela minha lógica, eu teria que armazenar esse conteúdo em uma variável e então percorrê-la para que as modificações sejam feitas. A "*grifagem*" das palavras obedece uma condição de tamanho. Palavras com determinadas quantidade de caracteres serão grifadas de uma determinada cor.

Inicialmente eu transformei a `string` em um `array` para poder percorrê-lo. No `for`, eu apliquei as condições para mudança de cor. Minha dúvida é como usar o conteúdo do parágrafo  dentro do laço e como de fato realizar a alteração das cores.

O que eu fiz até agora:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Faça elevar o cosmo no seu coração
        Todo o mal combater
        Despertar o poder
        Sua constelação sempre irá te proteger
        Supera a dor e dá forças pra lutar.</br>

        Pegasus Fantasy
        Desejos a realizar
        Pois as asas e um coração sonhador
        Ninguém irá roubar.</br>

        Saint Seiya! Guerreiro das estrelas!
        Saint Seiya! Nada a temer! Hoea!
        Saint Seiya! Unidos por sua força!
        Saint Seiya! Pégasus até vencer!</br>
    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*script.js*

```
let texto = document.querySelector(p)
let texto_copia = texto //backup da variável

texto = texto.split(' ')


for (let index = 0; index < texto.length; index++) {
    let element = texto[index]
    if(element.length == 9){
        document.querySelector(texto).style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
    }else if(element.length == 6){
        document.querySelector(texto).style.backgroundColor = 'green'
    }else if(element.length == 5){
        document.querySelector(texto).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
    }

}
```

Comment: O que é "grifar"? (em Portugal não usamos essa palavra... )

Comment: @Sergio seria dar ênfase a uma determinada parte de um texto (e.g: **lorem ipsum** dolor sit amet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Vamos ver os erros:

- Você tentou pegar o elementp `p` em vez de `"p"`
- Quando você fez `texto = texto.split(' ');`, você tentou cortar um objeto, e não um texto. Para isso, você poderia usar `texto = texto.innerText.split(" ");`

Você pode fazer o seguinte código:

```js
const p = document.querySelector("p");
const texto = p.innerText;
const palavras = texto.split(" ");

for (let index = 0; index < palavras.length; index++) {
  let palavra = palavras[index];

  if (palavra.length == 9) {
    palavra = `<span style="color: red">${palavra}</span>`;
  } else if (palavra.length == 6) {
    palavra = `<span style="color: green">${palavra}</span>`;
  } else if (palavra.length == 5) {
    palavra = `<span style="color: yellow">${palavra}</span>`;
  }

  palavras[index] = palavra;
}

p.innerHTML = palavras.join(" ");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Faça elevar o cosmo no seu coração Todo o mal combater Despertar o poder
      Sua constelação sempre irá te proteger Supera a dor e dá forças pra
      lutar.<br />

      Pegasus Fantasy Desejos a realizar Pois as asas e um coração sonhador
      Ninguém irá roubar.<br />

      Saint Seiya! Guerreiro das estrelas! Saint Seiya! Nada a temer! Hoea!
      Saint Seiya! Unidos por sua força! Saint Seiya! Pégasus até vencer!<br />
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lucas, realmente haviam pontos onde eu me perdi. Agradeço o feedback. Sobre o grifar, a ideia se assemelha a passar um marca texto por cima de uma palavra, entende? Algo como usar o background-color, porém apenas na palavra. Sua solução foi excelente, acredito que eu consiga adaptar!